# Probability: Inventory exercise

Tags: probability

A computer store is getting ready to order a batch of computers to sell during
the coming summer. The wholesaler is giving the store a good price on the computers
because they are being phased out and will not be available after the summer.
Each computer will cost the store \$550 to purchase, and they will sell it for \$995.
The wholesaler has also offered to buy back any unsold equipment for \$200. The
manager of the computer store estimates that demand for the computer over the
summer is a Poisson random variable. How many computers should be purchased
by the store in preparation for the summer if the mean demand for the summer is 5?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you edited into your question what you had tried and where you were stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well known that in the [Newsvendor Inventory Problem](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-772j-d-lab-supply-chains-fall-2014/calendar/MIT15_772JF14_Newsboy.pdf) the optimum quantity is the following

$$Q^*=F^{-1}\Big(\frac{995-550}{995-350}\Bigg)=F^{-1}(0.69)$$

Where $350=550-200$ is the sell-back cost

Considering a poisson distribution: $X\sim Po(5)$ you have that

$$\sum_{x=0}^5 \frac{e^{-5}5^x}{x!}\approx 0.62$$

$$\sum_{x=0}^6 \frac{e^{-5}5^x}{x!}\approx 0.76$$

the optimum quantity is between 5 and 6, say $x=6$